# Emulated device in chrome are missing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Unable to see the emulated device on chrome. This is my version 42.0.2311.152 (64-bit)

Really appreciate if someone could help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried installing the Google Chrome Canary and I did not face this issue :)
Here is the link https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html